# Swift 3 Ambiguous Class name

Tags: swift3, ios10

I am in the process of converting my code to swift 3. I have an Objective C class "Dimension", which has been working fine in swift 2.3. now I getting the following error.

```
'Dimension' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *@Natarajan* already described, your class name is now in conflict with another class of the OS.

If you don't want to rename your class you can identify your class prefixing the name of your project to the name of the class.

So every time you reference `Dimension`

```
let dimension: Dimension = ...
```

change your code like shown below

```
let dimension:YourProjectName.Dimension = ...
```

Comment: I have this problem when importing a Swift class that imports Foundation. Both use "Category". Can I configure a project prefix in ObjC too?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Swift 3.0 has removed the 'NS' from the most of NS classes. So, iOS Foundation framework has [NSDimension](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdimension?language=objc) class and it's renamed to [Dimension](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dimension) in Swift 3.0. So It could be the reason for the above error. You may have to consider renaming your Dimension class(ex : CustomDimension).

Note: NSDimension class only available in iOS10+.

Comment: The problem is that I have archived data associated with my Dimension class and if I change the name of the class it can not unarchive the old Dimension class data, causing a crash.

Comment: Is there anyway to force it look for the Dimension class in my project.